# Hyperledger Fabric docker-compose CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I have some organizations with more than 2 peers. When I was editing the docker-compose-base.yaml, I am not sure how to define CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP. Below is what I did, but the log showed that the peer fails to connect to the gossip peers. What is the correct way to do so? Thank you in advance!

**docker-compose-base.yaml**

```
peer0.caseManager.snts.com:
    container_name: peer0.caseManager.snts.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.caseManager.snts.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.caseManager.snts.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=[peer1.caseManager.snts.com:7051 peer2.caseManager.snts.com:7051]
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.caseManager.snts.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=CaseManagerMSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/caseManager.snts.com/peers/peer0.caseManager.snts.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/caseManager.snts.com/peers/peer0.caseManager.snts.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer0.caseManager.snts.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
      - 9051:7051
      - 9053:7053
```

**log of "docker-compose -p docker-compose.yaml up"**

```
peer0.caseManager.snts.com    | 2018-11-15 16:21:18.420 UTC [gossip/discovery] func1 -> WARN 023 Could not connect to {peer2.caseManager.snts.com:7051] [] [] peer2.caseManager.snts.com:7051] <nil> <nil>} : context deadline exceeded
peer0.caseManager.snts.com    | 2018-11-15 16:21:18.420 UTC [gossip/discovery] func1 -> WARN 024 Could not connect to {[peer1.caseManager.snts.com:7051 [] [] [peer1.caseManager.snts.com:7051 <nil> <nil>} : context deadline exceeded
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a peer's perspective, the Bootstrap peer is another peer from the same Organization, who it can reach out to during bootstrap and get some necessary info to get communication going. ([see here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.3/sampleconfig/core.yaml#L126))

Your setup looks correct, and its perfectly plausible that your Peer0 started up earlier than Peer1 and Peer2 and was unable to find these during startup, but that's not out of ordinary. Did you end up having any error? If not, this looks like normal operation.

Comment: So can the peers still know each other after bootstrap, like in the normal app operations?

Comment: Btw if I hide the log, it is all running ok

Comment: From what you have shared, yes, they should know each other. It should be visible in the logs too. And as you said there were no errors, I think you can ignore these warning messages, as they most probably have reconciled eventually.

Comment: And if this answer helped you, please consider up-voting it or selecting it as the correct answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

`- CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.caseManager.snts.com:7051 peer2.caseManager.snts.com:7051`